# Color transition in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, transition

I want to make a color transition of `Background` color of a WPF window.

**How can I do this?**

For example:

```
Brush i_color = Brushes.Red; //this is the initial color
Brush f_color = Brushes.Blue; //this is the final color
```

When I click on `Button` button1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Background = f_color; //here the transition begins. I don't want to be quick. Maybe an interval of 4 seconds.
}
```

Comment: @downvoter Why? Feel free to comment

Comment: +1 I don't get why this is down-voted. The question is clear and there's some code demonstrating what the OP wants.

Comment: @John: Downvote was probably for the lack of displayed effort to solve the problem on your own (see down-arrow tooltip). Also i am sure this has been asked before so the search effort could be questioned as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In code it can be done with this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ColorAnimation ca = new ColorAnimation(Colors.Red, Colors.Blue, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(ca, this);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ca, new PropertyPath("Background.Color"));

    Storyboard stb = new Storyboard();
    stb.Children.Add(ca);
    stb.Begin();
}
```

As H.B. pointed out this will work too

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ColorAnimation ca = new ColorAnimation(Colors.Blue, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)));
    this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    this.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, ca);
}
```

Comment: Having s storyboard for a single animation is a bit redudant, you could just use [`BeginAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.beginanimation.aspx) instead.

Comment: @H.B. `this.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, ca);` throws an exception *Cannot animate the 'Color' property on 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' because the object is sealed or frozen*. If you know how to solve this please share your knowledge.

Comment: @LPL: You just need to make sure *not* to use a frozen instance of a `SolidColorBrush`, e.g. set the `Background` to `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)`, then animate that. The instances from `Brushes` are probably all frozen so they cannot be changed (which would be weird, imagine someone taking the `Brushes.Red` and now it's blue).

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid x:Name="BackgroundGrid" Background="Red">

        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            Transition
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGrid" From="Red" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Do you want C# code to start the animation, or C# code to define the animation?

Comment: @John: This answer does what you want already, it changes color upon click, there is no need to use the event handler and code behind.

Comment: That's fine - I answered with what came to mind first.  I did like the ColorAnimation approach (I wasn't aware of that option) so I updated my answer in case anyone else can ever use it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) (read this), specifically a [`ColorAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation.aspx) (see examples) or [`ColorAnimationUsingKeyframes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimationusingkeyframes.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete LPL and H.B. answer.....
In my case I needed to revert a control back to the same color it was before the animation.

Here is my code

```
ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation()
{
    From = Colors.Orange,
    To = ((SolidColorBrush)myControl.Background).Color,//Revert to initial control Color
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
};

myControl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);//Do not use a frozen instance
myControl.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
```

Comment: I wanted to have an instant Orange color then fading back to "Control color".  Autoreverse would allow to fade from "Control Color" to Orange then back to "Control color".

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your background to a color and then use this xaml for a window to repeatedly change to the other color specified:

```
<Window.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation To="White" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
  </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```