# Animate XAML ListBox Item Background Colour

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML that displays a grid of Summaries

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="336,60,10,63">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="4">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="8">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="16">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="32">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                <Label Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="{Binding CurrentState}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid  Columns="4"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Currently the Background Colour of the ListBox item is set based on the value of Status, when the value changes the BackGround colour changes correctly.

What I would like to do is Animate/transition from one colour to the next as the value of State changes.

I've been having a search on here and have come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617216/color-transition-in-wpf) which suggests I need to be using

```
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGrid" From="Red" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" />
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

presumably inside my `<DataTrigger></DataTrigger>`

**Problem 1:** The first thing I noticed is the From colour is specified in the example above but I wont know what colour the item is transitioning from

**Problem 2:** It appears that `<BeginStoryBoard></BeginStoryBoard>` isn't valid syntax inside a `<DataTrigger></DataTrigger>`

As you can probably tell this is the first time I've played around with XAML animations so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure offhand how to handle Problem 2, but Problem 1 is easy enough:  Just don't include the `From` part of the animation.  It will work just fine with only the `To`.

Comment: See [How to: Trigger an Animation When Data Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970679(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem as mentioned by @Stewbob don't include the `From` part in your animation, it will work fine.
You can solve your second problem by defining Enter and Exit Action on your DataTrigger like this:

```
                    <DataTrigger Binding="" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation> //your color animation </ColorAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                             <ColorAnimation> <ColorAnimation />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
```

One thing to note here is that EnterActions and ExitActions set values permanently while simple Setters will only set temporary values that will be applied as long as the property condition is fulfilled in the Trigger.